# TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

tengo el siguiente problema, esto es lo que llevaba de código:
primero hice un plot, este si me salió bien:

```
cuantil = Tciudades.quantile([.20,.56,.70],axis = 0) 
plt.plot(cuantil , marker="*" )
plt.xlabel("Porcentaje")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura")
```

Ahora lo que quiero lograr es hacer un diagrama de barras, hice algo así:

```
plt.xlabel("Porcentaje")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura")
plt.bar(cuantil, width = 0.1)
plt.show()
```

Pero no me salió, me arroja el siguiente error y solo me bota lo que seria el xlab y ylab:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-504078c7784f> in <module>
      1 plt.xlabel("Porcentaje")
      2 plt.ylabel("Temperatura")
----> 3 plt.bar(cuantil, width = 0.1)
      4 plt.show()

TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje del error ya te dice el problema que tenés.

**Falta un argumento en el método bar(), el nombre del argumento que falta es 'height'**.

Si buscás en [la documentación de Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) vas a ver los parámetros que tenés que pasarle a bar().

Uno de esos parámetros es *height*.

> height: float or array-like. The height(s) of the bars. [Matplotlib.](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html?highlight=bar#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)

Ejemplo:

```
plt.xlabel("Porcentaje")
plt.ylabel("Temperatura")
plt.bar(cuantil, 0.8, width = 0.1) # height = 0.8, cambiá este valor según tu necesidad.
plt.show()
```